# Add different PHP version to docker-composer

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, config

I'm new to docker and stumbling into a PHP issue.

I can add a WordPress site, Database and phpmyadmin with no issues.

The theme I am using requires PHP version >=8.1.0.

Message displayed:

*Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0".*

Below is the docker-compose.yml file

```
# version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: WP_name
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
      # - ./src:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: dbname
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      # WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX : ''
    ports:
      - 8081:80

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql_WP
    restart: always
    command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    #volumes:
      #  - ./database_dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/exampledb.sql
    volumes:
       - ./schema:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8082:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORT: password

  php:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
```

The PHP build dockerfile at the bottom of docker-compose.yml (Dockerfile) contains:

`FROM php:8.1.23-fpm-alpine`

Can someone please advise on how I can add PHP version >=8.1.23 to the site (as an image?) in docker?

Any help much appreciated

Tried adding a Dockerfile in /php containing `FROM php:8.1.23-fpm-alpine`

Comment: Not sure to understand. `FROM php:8.1.23-fpm-alpine` was already present in your Dockerfile on your first build or did you change it after the error? Also, are you running `composer` inside or outside your containers?

Comment: Hi @AlbertoFecchi I added the FROM php:8.1.23-fpm-alpine to the Dockerfile on the first build. RE composer...I ran composer install outside of the container. Any advice to run it within a container would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See my answer, this seems to be the solution you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Run `docker-compose exec php composer install` to run `composer install` inside your container (which runs PHP 8.1.2)

If you want to open a shell to run more commands, use `docker-compose php sh`.

Comment: Am I to run `docker-compose exec php composer install` in the terminal or to add to the php/Dockerfile?

Comment: In terminal. I suggest you to study first chapters of Docker/docker-compose documentations on the official website, if you miss these basics you can't go on using Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the wordpress image to the below works

```
wordpress:6.3.1-php8.1-apache
```

Full docker-compose.yml file

```
# version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql_WP
    restart: always
    command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    # volumes:
    #    - ./schema:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8082:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORT: password

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:6.3.1-php8.1-apache
    container_name: WP_name
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
      # - ./src:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: dbname
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      # WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX : ''
    ports:
      - 8081:80
```